# Objeto não existe quando um foreach está dentro de outro, exceto durante depuração

Tags: javascript

No meu código eu consultei 2 serviços e coloquei seus resultados (objetos) dentro de um array chamado `deferreds`.

Estes objetos têm uma propriedade chamada `results`, que é outro `array`.

Eu preciso pegar o primeiro desses objetos, e dar um `push()` de todos os `results` dos outros objetos nele, pois vou exibi-lo em um `popup`.

Meu problema é que isso só funciona quando eu coloco um `breakpoint` no navegador e vou indo linha a linha. Quando eu rodo normal no navegador, ele dá um erro dizendo que `def.results[0]` é indefinido, mas quando eu vou devagar `debugando` ele tem sim um valor, e tudo roda normal.

Alguma dica?

```
var deferred = null;
deferreds.forEach(function (def) {
    if (deferred == null) {
        deferred = def;
    } else {

        def.results[0].forEach(function (defer) {
            deferred.results[0].push(defer);
        });
    }
});


this.mapa.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);
this.mapa.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);
```

Comment: fazendo def.results[0].forEach você não esta percorrendo o array, você esta acessando apenas o valor, que por si so não pode ser percorrido. retira esse [0] ai que vai funcionar :D da um console.log() ae e pega o  objeto

Comment: O que dá `console.log(JSON.stringify(deferreds));`? Podes colocar o código dos dois serviços que consultas?

Comment: Eu acho que você está tentando acessar os resultados antes que o deferred tenha sido resolvido.

Comment: Obrigado @GabrielRodrigues, é que dentro do results havia um array. A primeira posição com os objetos que citei, e outro vazio. Por isso que eu colocava [0].

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto. Não tenho certeza mas acho que o problema era esse mesmo. Consegui resolver usando o `when` do DOJO Framework que estou usando, pra acessar a propriedade de cada `results`

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio, acho que o problema era que a deferred não estava pronta mesmo. Já posto como resolvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valeu pessoal, acho que o problema era que a deferred não estava pronta mesmo. (Acho). 
Resolvi usando o `When` do DOJO framework assim:

```
var deferred = deferreds[0];

var teste;

for (var i = 1, max = deferreds.length; i < max; i++) {
    when(deferreds[i], function (results) { teste = results; });

    when(deferred, function (results) {

        teste.forEach(function (item) {
            results.push(item);
        });
    });
}

this.mapa.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);
this.mapa.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa, blz?
Cara, se seu objetivo é colocar todos os results no primeiro objeto do seu array, não seria melhor vc fazer assim:

```
var first = null;
if(deferreds.length > 1) {
  first = deferreds.shift()
  deferreds.forEach(function (item) {
    first.result = first.result.concat(item.result);
  });    
} else {
  first = deferreds[0]
}

first.result
```